# What is the difference between assets and resources?

Tags: support, tags

I just asked [a question about resources management](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/108800/how-to-find-resources-location-regardless-of-working-directory), but on the tagging part, I got stuck on a point: should I tag it `assets` or `resources`?

The tags description are the follwing:

#### [Assets](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/tags/assets/info)

> Game resources separate from the software (code) and hardware
>   (platform). The most common assets are graphics and audio.
>
> Questions under the purview of this tag tend to focus on the
>   management and handling of assets in the game. It can also cover other
>   aspects of less common assets, such as reference files or external map
>   data.

#### [Resources](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/tags/resources/info)

> Term 'resource' represents a game content item: an audio file, video
>   clip, sprite animation image, etc.

So how to choose which one to tag? Does `resources` focus more on precise files and assets more about global management?

Comment: You can always tag both though

Comment: @MosesAprico No, not always. The tag limit is 5, so if I already have 4 others, I cannot. And if I am not sure of what do they mean, one of both can be irrelevant.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think there is a meaningful differences within the context of this site, I would think `resources` should be a synonym of `assets`.

Comment: I agree, they should be marked as such.

Comment: I've done this.

Answer (score 3):

I would like to offer an addition answer to this question as it seems that these two words are often *confused*. An **asset** is really a *sub-category* of **resource**. And this is really contextual.

For example, a REST endpoint is often termed as a remote 'resource'. However, we don't deem it an asset, because the remote gateway is dynamic, and may return a plethora of data from an immense result-space. (these data may be referred to as assets however.)

An image, swf, sound, or a CSS file, or a JavaScript document which are generally stored statically on your web server or your content data network, to be loaded statically by the client is usually referred to as a specific type of resource: an "Asset" Resource.

Did you know, that you also have "Human Resources" working at your company. They hire "Human Resources", not "Human Assets" :).

This is just a take from a Distributed Applications perspective, where we definitely differentiate between the two.

Sometimes on contained projects which use a small variety of 'resources', these two words cannot be differentiated. Every asset is a resource, and every resource is an asset.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

IMO, "things" called "resource" until you build your game, and when you build, they become "assets". Because resource is something that you need to make another thing. But an asset is a thing that belongs to another thing. *(so many "thing"s here)*

Comment: That's a reasonable, but fairly subjective interpretation and I don't think it's a useful enough distinction for us to keep them separate on the site.